# How to avoid boilerplate when writing wrapper classes or functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have found myself writing a wrapper class over many back-end classes which implement similar interfaces. The rudimentary version looks like this:

```python
class Wrapper(BackendInterface):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Instantiate/initialize backend classes
        self._b1 = BackendOne(...)
        self._b2 = BackendTwo(...)
        ...

    def _select_backend(self, ...):
        # Select backend based on runtime requirements
        if condition_one:
            return self._b1
        elif condition_two:
            return self._b2
        ...

    def method_one(self, foo, bar, baz, alpha, beta, gamma, delta, ...):
        b = self._select_backend(...)
        b.method_one(foo, bar, baz, alpha, beta, gamma, delta, ...)

    def method_two(self, a, b, c, d, ...):
        b = self._select_backend(...)
        b.method_two(a, b, c, d, ...)

    ...
```

As shown above, many (but not all) of the methods boil down to a back-end selection followed by a call to the same method on the back-end object. In many cases, even the method signature is identical. Is there a way to avoid this boilerplate mess?

I have considered using locals() at the top of each method.

```python
...
def method_one(self,  foo, bar, baz, alpha, beta, gamma, delta, ...):
    args = locals() # Must be the first line!
    del args['self']
    b = self._select_backend(...)
    b.method_one(**args)
...
```

I believe similar results can be obtained using the inspect module.

There are some problems with this approach though.
1. There is still a lot of boilerplate.
2. locals() call must be on the first line. I am pretty sure someone will try to 'optimize' the method at some point and mess it up.

Is there a better approach I can use??

I am also interested in knowing how to deal with such a situation in Java.

Note: I am using Python 2.7.11, if it matters.

**EDIT:** Removed the Java tag. I'll ask the question separately for Java. That way Python developers don't have to read Java code and vice-versa.

Comment: @LoganKulinski I am also interested in knowing how to deal with such a situation in Java.

Comment: Are you meaning boilerplate in Java as in getters/setters, constructor, hashCode, equals, toString, etc?

Comment: No - imagine a similar situation while writing Java code where I am trying to write a wrapper around multiple classes that implement the same interface. I am relatively new to Java - so please excuse me if I missed something obvious.

Comment: I can provide the equivalent Java code if it helps @LoganKulinski

Comment: That might be helpful. Would you only be using method declared in that single interface?

Comment: I'll add the Java code as well. And yes - all the back-ends Implement the same interface. The wrapper class will have to implement it as well. The purpose of the wrapper class is to select the correct back-end based on the run time conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing for Python

```python
class Wrapper(BackendInterface):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Instantiate/initialize backend classes
        self._b1 = BackendOne(...)
        self._b2 = BackendTwo(...)
        ...

    def __dispatch_to_backend(method):
        @functools.wraps(method, updated=[])
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            method_impl = getattr(self._select_backend(...), method.__name__)
            return method_impl(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    def _select_backend(self, ...):
        # Select backend based on runtime requirements
        if condition_one:
            return self._b1
        elif condition_two:
            return self._b2
        ...

    method_one = __dispatch_to_backend(BackendInterface.method_one)
    method_one = __dispatch_to_backend(BackendInterface.method_two)

    ...
```

I guess this is about as boilerplate free as it gets.

Comment: You might be able to go one step further and get a list of BackendInterface's methods at runtime, and then call your decorator on each.

Comment: @Harvey: Not all methods follow the exact same pattern - there are some which have to be implemented differently. I'll end up maintaining a list of methods this pattern is applicable to.

Comment: Additionally, if I add the methods at run-time, python doesn't consider the interface implemented. It is not strictly necessary, but desirable. There are workarounds, but they end up adding more boilerplate.

Comment: Might be easier to maintain a list in `Wrapper.__init__` of applicable method names to run through that wrapper decorator. Also, a nitpick, the decorator belongs inside the Wrapper class. I've used a pattern in the past where only a set of methods needed modifying. So we named them all something like `set_...` so the wrapping code could be dynamic.

Comment: See my last comment about the interface implementation and method addition at run-time. Can you share an example of what you did? Remember, I can't alter the back-end APIs at all. That is the sole reason I have to write the wrapper.

Comment: And I know the decorator belongs inside the class - that is how I actually did it. Will update the example code above.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can just accept `*args` - or `*args, **kwargs` - in the methods and pass those up to the backend?

```
def method_one(self, *args, **kwargs):
    b = self._select_backend(...)
    b.method_one(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I can do that, but this approach is still only slightly better than the locals() approach in terms of boilerplate reduction. And I will need to add code to check all arguments are present.